# symfony2 asks for intl extension and its already installed

Tags: macos, symfony, osx-yosemite, intl

I installed installed intl extension by setting extension=intl.so in my php.ini on my Macbook Pro Yosemite

[image: see image]

but still symfony 2.7 is asking for it. See in the picture the error. 
Does anyone have any idea how to solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the php.ini that Symfony is using is the same as the one where you updated the extension. Especially on OS X, where one might install HomeBrew based PHP Versus the one that came with OS X.

I typically add a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in my web directory and load that file to see which PHP Symfony is using.

Comment: The loaded php.ini file is /etc/php.ini. I have already installed the intl extension using these instructions                                                           Intl extension

If you need Locale:

brew install icu4c
sudo pecl install intl
The path to the ICU libraries and headers is: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/
Edit /etc/php.ini and add extension=intl.so to the end. but php.ini still shows that the intl extension is not loaded :(.